# What does the following piece of code do

Tags: c

```
short rtimer_arch_now(void)
{
  short t1, t2;
  do {
    t1 = TA1R;
    t2 = TA1R;
  } while(t1 != t2);
  return t1;
}
```

TA1R is a The Timer_A Register. I still dont get why there is a loop. If they want to return the time whydont they simply return TA1R. What is the loop for?

Comment: TA1R can change values between the times it is read as it is a register.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It tries to avoid the case when you ask the current time but it returns the value right before the time ticks. So it only returns the current time if the reading is stable.

Comment: Yep. That makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

The code is attempting to wait until `TA1R` changes and then return the old value of `TA1R`.

This code will only work if `TA1R` was declared as `volatile`, otherwise the compiler can optimize the loop away.

Comment: What if subsequent reads of the timer (t1 and t2) continually return different values? This doesn't seem a robust solution if the timer has a high frequency.

Comment: Also, your answer is incorrect - note the `!=` in `while (t1 != t2)`

Comment: agreed that this is not a robust solution.

Comment: whoops, I didn't notice the `!=` in the while loop, so perreal's answer is correct. The code is avoiding returning the value when the timer has just changed.